# Why I get maximum call stack size exceeded when using mixins with jade/pug

Tags: node.js, pug, mean, mixins

I cannot get a mixin to work with pug

template file:

```
row
  .col-sm-6.col-md-4.col-lg-8.pagination-centered
     form
       input.form-control(type='text', placeholder='What do you need?',  required='')
       p
       select.form-control(name='city', placeholder='City', required='')
       +getCities(cities)
       p 
       button.btn.btn-primary.center-block(type='submit') search
```

included file with mixin

```
mixin getCities(cities)
    - each city in cities
      option #{city}
```

Answer (score 1):

If anyone has a similar problem.

I eventually figured it out. Option
needed to be indented in both cases

mixin file:

```
mixin selectCity(cities) 
      each city in cities
        option #{city}
```

jade file:

```
row
  .col-sm-6.col-md-4.col-lg-8.pagination-centered
    form
       input.form-control(type='text', placeholder='What do you need?',  required='')
       p
       select.form-control(name='city', placeholder='City', required='')
         +getCities(cities)
     p 
    button.btn.btn-primary.center-block(type='submit') search
```